# Что то DotPeek не показывает то, что было сгенерировано. Как сделать, чтоб показывал?

Tags: .net, .net-core, reverse-engineering, декомпиляция

Я хочу взять `.exe`/`.dll`, где в исходном коде использовался `async/await` и посмотреть, что там генерирует компилятор. Увидеть глазами и потрогать руками эту самую Машину состояний. Вот такой код написал:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task KekAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current thread id before await {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Current thread id after await {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Current thread id after await again {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Current thread id after await again and again {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await KekAsync();
    }
}
```

Нажимаю Release. В настройках DotPeek выставил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, то есть, show compiler-generated code, судя по названию, и должен за это отвечать.

Загружаю скомпилированный файл и вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А где машина состояний? Где генерация? Вижу просто мой исходный код. Так не интересно( Как посмотреть, что генерирует компилятор для async/await?

P.S. пробовал на .NET Core 3.1 и на последней версии .NET Framework. Работаю на Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

А, все, разобрался. Правой кнопкой на файл -> Decompiled Sources

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]